# renaming product description title with custom sentence including product name

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, field-description

i've been trying to write

> WHY 'MY PRODUCT TITLE'

In the product description tab, i've successfully renamed it with

> 'MY PRODUCT TITLE'

but i can't type the remaining word

> WHY

in the description title tab.

the code i used is given below:

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 
            'wc_change_product_description_tab_title', 10, 1 );
           function wc_change_product_description_tab_title( $tabs ) {
              global $post;
                if ( isset( $tabs['description']['title'] ) )
                $tabs['description']['title'] =  $post->post_title;
              return $tabs; 
}
```

this code prints the product title and when i try this code so that i can type

> why

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs',
'wc_change_product_description_tab_title', 10, 1 );
function wc_change_product_description_tab_title( $tabs ) {
  global $post;
  if ( isset( $tabs['description']['title'] ) )
  $tabs['description']['title'] =  'WHY'.' '.$post->post_title;
  return $tabs;
}
```